# when i turn on b-bones i don't get the blocks

Tags: modeling, armature, bones

I am following this tutorial on how to rig and am trying to do a very basic rig for arms. Now in this tutorial he says that for the hand controller i copy the bone, scale it up and turn on b-bones. When he turns on the b-bones he gets these blocks but when i turn on the b-bones i get something more akin to sticks. i can't scale these sticks on any axis other then the y axis and don't know how to fix it.

what they are supposed to look like:

[image: 1]

What they look like when i do it:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to thicken the B-Bones:

[image]

Comment: thank you. this works